# Second internal hard drive on Mac won't mount

Tags: hard-drive, mount, macbook-pro

I recently installed a second hard drive on my MacBook, with an SSD now being the primary drive and the second hard drive now in SATA slot where the superdrive was.

It worked perfectly for a week or so but now I can't even mount the hard drive and it appears to be treating the hard drive as a super drive disc.

I've tried to mount it several times with no success and I've unplugged and replugged the hard drive in.

This is what I currently see on disk utility:

[image]

I'm looking for some guidance or some trouble-shooting steps or is it just a case Apple no longer support this kind of setup? I've tried 'googling' this issue but with no success.

Comment: Make sure that the HD works in other circumstances with an external USB->SATA enclosure or adapter.

Comment: Usual fail-point for MacBooks is the SATA cable; check it's firmly fitted & no signs of damage, though often the fail is not visible & the only test without specialist equipment is try a new one & see.

Comment: BTW, Pro Tip: To to take a screenshot... Cmd/shift/4 then tap the spacebar & the cursor will turn into a camera icon. Clicking over any window will then screenshot just that window, complete with drop-shadow.

Comment: Thanks for the first two tips, I though that might be only steps left @ChristopherHostage and Tetsujin. I'll take it apart and test, then update my results here.